# Logging in to an ASP website with cURL

Tags: php, asp.net, curl

I'm trying to access content that requires me to log in to a site, however the site is written in ASP and I'm having trouble authenticating. Here is the login form

```
<form method="post" action="LoginTemplates/DefaultLogin.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="LoginForm">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="adfsagasdfe2342a#$@ASF@">
</div>
<input name="LoginTextBox" type="text" id="LoginTextBox" class="TextBox" placeholder="Enter username here">
<input name="PasswordTextBox" type="password" id="PasswordTextBox" class="TextBox" placeholder="Enter password here">
<input type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="Sign in" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;SubmitButton&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="SubmitButton" class="btn btn-primary right">
</form>
```

Here is my code

```
$url="https://www.example.com/LoginTemplates/DefaultLogin.aspx";
$login="login@test.com";
$password="password";

$ch = curl_init();    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
$cookie = 'cookies.txt';
$timeout = 30;

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,         10); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,  $timeout );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,       $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,      $cookie);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt        ($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"LoginTextBox=".urlencode($login)."&PasswordTextBox=".urlencode($password));                 

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does that ASP page have CSRF protection?...  'value="adfsagasdfe2342a#$@ASF@">'

Comment: There is one more field I missed, not sure if this is the CSRF protection        <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="sdfgsdfgsdfg243$@#$$32" /> @Tejas